# Decrese value on FIFO by primary SQL

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have tabels like this..

| id | code | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | ABC | 10 |
| 2 | A2 | BCD | 20 |
| 3 | A1 | ABC | 30 |
| 4 | A1 | ABC | 10 |
| 5 | A3 | EDC | 30 |

i want to decrese quantity with this tabel..

| code | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | ABC | 45 |
| A2 | BCD | 5 |

then i want the result like this.

| id | code | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | ABC | 0 |
| 2 | A2 | BCD | 15 |
| 3 | A1 | ABC | 0 |
| 4 | A1 | ABC | 5 |
| 5 | A3 | EDC | 30 |

i have no idea for this case. thanks..

Comment: 10.4.22-MariaDB

Comment: Cumulative sum in CTE and according decreasing.

Comment: CTE.? sorry what the meaning.?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/common-table-expressions/ and https://mariadb.com/kb/en/aggregate-functions-as-window-functions/

Comment: ok ill try.. thanks

Comment: how about using loop/for for this case.?

Comment: Please show the code that you came up with, and explain the problem you might have with it. (I do think a loop can only be used in stored procedures, so you will have to write a stored procedure)

Comment: sorry i can't explain.. but how is : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=44f0d7dbdb8f32c3a17b1a4e53f554cb

Comment: my latest update, but capital price is keeping up with the latest stuff https://dbfiddle.uk/Thtq5FeV